# Data dependencies using gcc dump

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, dependencies, static-analysis

I have some `C/C++` code.

I want to get information about the `data dependencies` within a function e.g.
If there is a variable declared in line 1 and used in line 2 then i want to know this dependency.

I could analyse the control flow graph produced by the option `-fdump-tree-fixupcfg-lineno` [GCC Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) in gcc, but things can get complicated because of `pointers` and either indirect uses of variables/arrays etc.

I am not in the compiler domain, but at some stage the compiler should find these dependencies in order to assign registers to the variables. 
Any ideas if I can get this information from any of the gcc dumps?